What is the benefit of Axios' type variable for response data?
Axios request functions are typed as
get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>

(delete, post, etc. are analogously typed), where AxiosResponse has the following definition:
export interface AxiosResponse<T = any>  {
  data: T;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  headers: any;
  config: AxiosRequestConfig;
  request?: any;
}

So using Axios I can provide a type for T, e.g. axios.get<{id: number}>(...).
Therefore, I get the return type <Promise<AxiosResponse<{id: number}>>, which leads to the following code to type check:
const data: {id: number} = await axios.get<number>(...).then((response) => response.data)

So my question is:
Did Axios ever validate the response data? Or might I as well do the following and get the same "safety"?
const data: {id: number} = 
  await axios.get<unknown>(...).then((response) => response.data as {id: number})

And if this doesn't give me any safety, what is the purpose of this type variable?

TypeScript only exists at compile time, and the result of a network request cannot be known before it is sent and received, so the only way to statically type the response data is to narrow it using runtime validation or to use a type assertion. Validation provides runtime safety in exchange for additional computational complexity, while type assertions rely on a contractual assumption… neither is "better" — they both have trade-offs.

Good point! I just wish the type of T would be unknown, and then the user of the library is forced to use response.data as myType to make clear, that this is only an assertion and there is no prior validation happening in get.
